# Why does CreateFile fail intermittently?

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io, filesystems

The following code fails every few dozen to a few hundred iterations with Permission Denied on CreateFile. I ran it on Windows 8.1 (x64) as well as on Windows 7 (x86):

```
while(true) {
    auto file = CreateFileA(
        "test.txt",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "create failed: " << std::error_code(GetLastError(), 
            std::system_category()).message() << std::endl;
        continue;
    }

    if (!CloseHandle(file)) 
        std::cerr << "close failed: " << std::error_code(GetLastError(), 
            std::system_category()).message() << std::endl;

    if (!DeleteFileA("test.txt"))
        std::cerr << "delete failed: " << std::error_code(GetLastError(), 
            std::system_category()).message() << std::endl;
}
```

I presume that something in the system is temporarily holding an open handle to it, so DeleteFile marks it for deletion and happily continues but the following create then fails. There is an old post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/09/07/10347136.aspx), which discusses this behavior, however I have no anti-virus software installed and stopped the Windows Search service.

Comment: I don't know why the question was downvoted, but it's a legitimate question about a general behavior in Windows. It is *not* specific to my machine, as I said I've tested it on different machines with the same result. Also it might seem contrived but it's a real-life issue leading to intermittent failures, I just distilled down the code above for simplicity.

Comment: Use [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to see what's going on. Not really a programming question.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Of course it's a programming question! You can't write reliable software if the underlying file system behaves in an unreliable manner. It may not be a computer science question, but those of us who write software for a living are interested in practical matters too.

Comment: The underlying file system does not behave like this, it is perfectly predictable. Something on your particular system at this particular time is interfering. ProcMon can tell you what that is.

Comment: Let's try one more time. The way I see this, it is a fundamental issue with Windows. If it's a bug then it may or may no belong to so. If it is by design then it's more then relevant to understand this behavior.

Comment: The underlying file system is *supposed to be* perfectly predictable. Turns out it isn't. Hence my question.

Comment: I can't duplicate this error. I put it in a for loop with a 1000 iterations, it was fine.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Thanks for testing. I've tested it on 3 different systems and it fails. It is however a timing issue, i.e. retrying the CreateFile will succeed. What platform did you test it on?

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 with no anti-virus and I have also stopped search index.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Would you try running in an infinite loop? On one of my machines it takes 10K+ iterations to get it to fail.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I have *Windows Defender* running, but I have excluded my VS projects from *Real Time Protection*. If I run the project from a directory that's being checked then `CreateFile` fails after a few thousand iterations. I think my poor hard disk is having a hard time. I tried the same thing on a newer hard disk and then `CreateFile` failed after about 100,000 iterations. I didn't have a problem with `CloseHandle` or `DeleteFile` in either case.

Comment: Windows Defender was off in my case.

Comment: I suspect that Windows Vista and later do file deletions asynchronously, even if there are no handles open at the time DeleteFile is called.  But it would still be sensible to use Process Monitor to confirm that there really are no other handles.  (Although come to think of it even that won't be conclusive - presumably a kernel reference to the file would also prevent it from being deleted immediately.)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this has much practical impact, though, since almost all production code has to be able to cope when an anti-virus is present.  So in practice you almost always have to code defensively regardless of what Windows is doing under the hood.  One solution is to rename and/or move the file prior to deleting it.

Comment: You need to check for failure and re-try after a short time if you delete and immediately re-create a file. I encountered this 5-6 years ago, and still haven't found anyone who can explain why it happens. It's almost certainly a Windows bug, possibly hardware related.